# Cordova using ASP.NET WebService (.asmx) not woking

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, cordova

I am having a trouble using cordova and .asmx as my backend code. It always returning `undefined` error.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('#signin').click(function (e) {
        $('#frmLogin').validate();

        $('#uid').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: 'Input your username.'
            }
        });

        $('#upassword').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: 'Input your password.'
            }
        });

        if ($('#frmLogin').valid()) {
            var credentials = {}
            credentials.username = $('#uid').val();
           credentials.password = $('#upassword').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/WebService/WebService.asmx/Signin',
                data: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here's my code in `.asmx` file

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>    <ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class WebService
  Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Signin(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As String
    Dim AccountStatus As String = (New Account.Membership).GetAccountStatus(username, password)

    Return AccountStatus
End Function
End Class
```

It should suppose to return what's inside the `AccountStatus` value.

**UPDATE**

Here's the error return in the console

> rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost/WebService/WebService.asmx%3Fop%3DSignin:1 POST https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost/WebService/WebService.asmx%3Fop%3DSignin 500 (Internal Server Error)

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

I got it now. I just added

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

in `web.config` file

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What undefined error.show the full error log

Comment: The error is server-side. Step through the WebMethod with the debugger.

Comment: @Crowcoder but when I try to navigate my `asmx` file using the `localhost/WebService.asmx/Signin` the return value is correct. So I thought there is no problem in my code.

Comment: @Rehmard Internal Server Error 500 means something went wrong on the server. That doesn't mean nothing is wrong with your javascript, but you need to fix the server code first.